# How do I exclude a model version from the finished archive?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

We have a few apps which share a lot of their codebases, including the core data model.  We've released version 2.3.0 of the apps, and we're working on 2.4.0.  There are corresponding versions in the data model, and 2.4.0 isn't finished.

We now need to release 2.3.1, which will have a small tweak to the data model.  I want the apps to contain the data model versions for 2.3.0 and 2.3.1, but I don't want them to include the 2.4.0 work-in-progress model version.

I can't build the app for release without checking everything into source control, and thanks to our lousy change control server, I can't delete the new model and restore it without causing horrible conflicts and loss of history.

In most places in Xcode, I can exclude a file from the build without deleting it, but I've checked and even if I delete the 2.4.0 model version from the pbxproj file by hand it still gets built into the xcarchive.

How do I exclude a model version from the finished archive without deleting it from the codebase?

Comment: This is why source code control systems like git (and pretty much every other one) have branches. Really your 2.3.1 work and your 2.4 work should be on different branches.

Comment: I agree, and we're working to move towards something more modern, but this is the problem I have right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tom's answer is the correct one.

But you can also just flag your 2.3 model as the current model and leave the 2.4 model in there.  No one will be able to access it since it is not the current model and nothing is migrating **FROM** it either.

It will be ignored by Core Data because Core Data is **NOT** temporal.  It doesn't care what you name the files.  It only cares about source and destination.

Comment: Thanks! Reassuring to know.